# ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath':

Tags: gradle

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot parse result path string:

Comment: add context and details